# How to make vertical lines between tabs in tabBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a tapBar with tabs, these tabs are clickable and I want to add divider between tabs but I don't understand how to do this in Flutter!

This is my tabBar:

```
TabBar(
  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
  indicator: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
    color: Color(0xFF1C1B20),
  ),
  labelColor: AppColors.whiteE3EAF6,
  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  tabs: [
    Tab(text: "1M",),
    Tab(text: "5M",),
    Tab(text: "15M",),
    Tab(text: "30M",),
    Tab(text: "1H",),
  ]
)
```

And I want to make it like this:

[image: This is what I want]

I tried to add Container between Tabs but this container moves all my tabs and became clickable and this is not what I really want.

Also this TabBar is inside Container and width of Container is 350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your tab inside container like this :

```
  Widget _tab(String text) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid))),
      child: Tab(
        text: text,
      ),
    );
  }
```

then create your tab :

```
TabBar(
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                indicator: ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                  color: Color(0xFF1C1B20),
                ),
                labelColor: AppColors.whiteE3EAF6,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), // remember to add this line
                tabs: [
                  _tab('1M'),
                  _tab('5M'),
                  _tab('15M'),
                  _tab('30M'),
                  _tab('1H'),
                ]
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this approach, this also fix divider over lapping issue**

first define new variable out of build method like this:

```
int selectedTap = 0;
```

then define tabWidget like this:

```
Widget tabWidget(String label, int index) {
    return Container(
      height: 15,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: index == selectedTap
          ? null
          : Border(
              right: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xFF454545),
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
            )),
      child: Tab(
        text: label,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
TabBar(
    controller: _controller,
    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    indicator: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      color: Color(0xFF1C1B20),
    ),
    labelColor: Colors.white,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    tabs: [
      tabWidget("1M", 0),
      tabWidget("5M", 1),
      tabWidget("15M", 2),
      tabWidget("30M", 3),
      Tab(
        text: "1H",
      ),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        selectedTap = index;
      });
    },
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

warp it with a container

```
Tab(
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 19, right: 19, bottom: 2),
      child: Text(
              "1M",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "PNU"),
            ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: do not forget to set height and width

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the tab with a container like this

```
 Container(
        height: 50,
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: 
         Colors.black, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid))),
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Tab(text: "1M"), //here the Tab widget
     )
    )
```

Comment: it didn't hep. The vertical line just comes close to a String, like this => 1m|

Comment: add padding to it, check the updated answer